# Mvvm pass textbox values from View to ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

The MVVM pattern is currently driving me crazy and seems to be a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

If want to pass an object from my View to my ViewModel, is there an easy way of doing this or do I need to create a getter / setter per variable and manually add them to an object.

I've also seen people work with PropertyInfo like this, but I can't seem to get the variables out of the object

Xaml code (shortened):

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="txbName" Text="Name: " FontSize="15"  Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding ProductToAdd.ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="txbWarehouse" Text="Warehouse: " FontSize="15" Margin="0, 10, 10, 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtWarehouse"Width="95" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Text="{Binding ProductToAdd.WarehouseID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add product" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"></Button>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }

    public AddProductPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        AddCommand = new CustomCommand(OnAddProduct, CanRedirect);
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName){
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Product ProductToAdd
    {
        get
        {
            return productToAdd;
        }
        set
        {
            productToAdd = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProductToAdd");
        }
    }

    private void OnAddProduct(object obj)
    {
        // Get all product vars 
        //Debug.Write(productToAdd.ProductName);
    }
```

Product code in Model:

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double MinimumTemperature { get; set; }
    public double MaximumTemperature { get; set; }
    public double MinimumHumidity { get; set; }
    public double MaximumHumidity { get; set; }
    public double MinimumAirPressure{ get; set; }
    public double MaximumAirPressure { get; set; }
    public int RackID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My bad, posted UML tag instead of UWP. I'm asking what the correct method would be to pass values from the View to the ViewModel using the MVVM pattern

Comment: I don't understand why you post this code as "ViewModel". It looks nothing like any code that I would expect as a ViewModel. How would you want to work with is thing? Also I'm kind of suspicious because you assign a `x:Name` to each of your xaml controls. In MVVM, you should hardly ever need a name there, because you don't need to reference the controls in code.

Comment: "The MVVM pattern is currently driving me crazy and seems to be a lot more complicated than it needs to be." I've added more code

Comment: Can you also show the `Product` definition?

Comment: Product is now added

Comment: I think you have not yet explained what you really want to do (and whats the specific problem). Because the binding should *somehow* work, even though it might be better to have property changed notification for each property.

Comment: I'm asking what the correct way to pass multiple values from View to ViewModel is. I understand that I can set a binding for every value, but that'd be very elaborate and does not seem to be the correct 'mvvm way'.
I'm just trying to add an object to my db..

Comment: Setting a binding per value is absolutely is the correct MVVM way and less elaborate in the long run.  It's easier to change, maintain, unit test, and is very straight forward once properly laid out.  If you don't value these things in your project than the MVVM pattern may not be what you need - though I've never found a project too small for it.

Comment: I would recommend to write out each property in XAML, but you can also have a look at [PropertyGrid](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Documentation) from Extended WPF Toolkit if you want to edit a single object or `DataGrid` if you want to maintain a list of objects without explicitely defining their view and editor controls.

Comment: This is the right way to do it, and you've already taken a shortcut with the ProductToAdd property. But not that you don't have full 2-way binding this way. The more elaborate (but better) ways is to replicate all the Name an Max,Min properties with their own notify.

Comment: Where and how do you set the `DataContext` of your view?

Comment: I've given up everything and am currently writing a getter/setter per input variable and adding these to the productToAdd

Comment: "and adding these to the productToAdd" - Wrong. Add them to the AddProductPageViewModel and learn how MVVM can be fun and productive.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel is usually bound to your View. Your AddCommand will then use the values to do what you want it to do. So, you should have a `ProductToAdd` property on your ViewModel.

You could pass the `ProductToAdd` object to the command by means of a `CommandParameter` as well, but it will still need to be defined somewhere and from your example it does not appear to be necessary.

Comment: Your Product model does not have a WarehouseID which - to me - could mean one of two things; 1, you forgot to add it, or 2. your product is a base class and warehouse is also a type of product. Apart from that, I don't see what the problem is. You have the bound object, and your Add button code can access it

Comment: I suspect the issue is that your model does not implement INotifiyPropertyChanged. In your case, the notify only fires when the model is updated, not when the properties inside it changes

Comment: ProductToAdd gets called when the view is loaded, but even though its mode is set to TwoWay it doesn't get called when there's data being added.
It seems I'm pretty bad at trying to explain what I want to do so here it is again:
I want to request all Product variables required to add a new product and send it to my viewmodel so I can add it to my DB

Comment: Yes. Because the properties do not notify that they changed.

Comment: OK, let's see; you have fields on your view that are bound to properties on ProductToAdd, right? Your properties don't notify of their change, but they should hold the values. Try setting ```UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged```

Comment: @woodsprite with MVVM you don't *send* anything to your viewmodel, but your viewmodel is the container and the view is displaying a visual representation of this container to the user. Just put a debugger breakpoint into your property setters and ensure that it is called right after you input values / lose focus on some input control.